# How do I plug transpose of a pivoted dataframe into np.corrcoef method?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Need to compute weekly success rate correlations

I've got weekly success rates for each sales person, as shown below:
[image: DataFrame].

This dataframe has been pivoted as follows:
[image: Pivoted DataFrame].

Now I want to find success rate correlations for consecutive weeks i.e. Week 46 vs week 47, week 47 vs week 48 and so on.

I'm okay with using `numpy.np.corrcoef` method, it will correlated every week with every other week but that's fine.

The problem is that I get weird results when I use this function:
[image: Pivoted DataFrame].

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**
`weekly_pivot['Success Rate'].corr()` worked just fine.